# rsync directory and contents to new location and owner

Tags: rsync

I have access to 2 group accounts: `ops_user` and `test_user`. Is it possible to copy a directory and all subdirectory owned by `ops_user` to a new directory owned by the test_user? I.e I want to copy everything from `/blah/Blah/ops` (owned by `ops-user`) to `/blah/Blah/test` (and have it owned by `test_user`). I've tried the following.

Logged in as `test_user` in `/blah/Blah/test`:

```
 rsync -avz */ ops_user@boco2:/blah/Blah/ops --owner=test_user --group=user 
 rsync -avzh ops_user@boco2:/blah/Blah/ops /blah/Blah/test/
 rsync -avz */ ops_user@boco2:/blah/Blah/ops
 rsync -avzhe ssh ops_user@boco2:/blah/Blah/ops /blah/Blah/test
```

Logged in as `ops_user` in `/blah/Blah/ops`:

```
'rsync -avz */ test_user@oco2:/blah/Blah/test'
```

None of these work. I read the man for rsync, but just can not figure this out. I do not have SA perms to change group owners, but thought I could copy and add test perms. Is rsync even what I should be using? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If test_user is not root, any copy he makes should end up with his user. Can you post the output of `ls -l` of a file from the rsync to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of `/blah/Blah/ops/` are public (that is, you can access them while logged in as `test_user`), then you can use a purely local rsync:

```
rsync -rltpDv /blah/Blah/ops/ /blah/Blah/test/
```

Note: the `/` after `ops` is important.  (If you leave it off, then rsync will copy the `ops` directory itself into the `test` directory in addition to its contents.)

If the contents are not currently public, you could make them public (as `ops_user`) just temporarily for the purposes of copying:

```
chmod -R go+rX /blah/Blah/ops
```

and then try the above `rsync` again.

If you can't make them public, then the rsync-over-ssh approach as `test_user` *should* work:

```
rsync -rltpDv ops_user@host:/blah/Blah/ops/ /blah/Blah/test/
```

although you may need to specify the `ssh` remote shell explicitly with `-e ssh`.  If this command *doesn't* work, what error message do you see?

Comment: The / after ops makes a difference, but saying it's "important" makes it sound like it's definitely wanted. It may or may not be wanted. I didn't see enough in the orig question to settle that.